# Properly measure of Process execution

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

How to properly measure `Process` runtime by `stopwatch`? Where to start, where to finish?

```
            this.Process.Start();

            StreamWriter streamWriter = this.Process.StandardInput;

            this.runtimeStopwatch.Start();
            streamWriter.Write(test);

            string output = this.Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            this.runtimeStopwatch.Stop();

            this.Process.WaitForExit();
```

For simple `process` for multiply two ints (`i * i`) runtime is something like `20-70ms`. I think its too long for so simply program.

Comment: Multiplying two integers in C# is very fast. Asking the operating system to spin up a new process to run an external program is (usually) not nearly as fast, regardless of what the program does. Also, a more accurate way to measure execution time might be to put the `Stopwatch.Stop()` after the `WaitForExit()`.